# Possible to make admin's flags worth more points?

Tags: users, flags

I'd like the admin's flagging of a node to carry more clout than with regular users. Is it possible to either;

- Insert the count into the mysql database as a number larger than 1
  whenever admin flags a node.
- Allow [flag](https://www.drupal.org/project/flag) counts to be additive, ie: Admin can flag a node many
  times with each count being added to the total.

Perhaps it can be done using [rules](https://www.drupal.org/project/rules) and php? If so what would be the procedure in rules?

Comment: I'd look into the https://drupal.org/project/fivestar module and hack at the code logic in it, eg, some roles/users votes count as 1 while others count as 2 or what have you.  It's all part of the https://drupal.org/project/votingapi so lots of ways to do it.

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by "hack at the code logic in it"?

Comment: meaning it probably doesn't do what you want exactly right away but there is probably a lot of code you could reuse to accomplish your exact goal in your own custom module.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Flags work like an on/off switch. Depending if the Flag is **global** or not, that on/off switch can apply to every user (each user can have a separate room w/ the lights on or off), or globally - every user is in one room, with only one light bulb, and one light switch.

Basically what you're asking is: *is it possible to turn on the lights on twice?*

No. In our light bulb analogy, that Flag switch doesn't come with a dimmer option ;)

What Rules allow you to do is aggregate the count of the Flag "votes" by multiple users (when not using global flags), and execute an action based on the sum of user "flags". But that is not what you're looking for.